# echo file name from image file for php

Tags: php

Hello everyone i need some help.  Can i do this? I'm working on a new script that has this PHP configuration.

```
<?php
function random_pic($dir, $nf=3)
{
$files = glob($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.jpg');
shuffle($files);
return array_pop($files);
}
//$number = rand(); ?v=$number
$path = 'images';
$file_images = random_pic($path, 1);
$image  = file_get_contents($file_images);
$og_img = base64_encode($image); 
?>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo basename($file_images)?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://YourDomain.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YourDomain.com/<?php echo $file_images ?>" />
```

the echo configuration changes the image file in every reload on the og:image and  og:title, changes the title automatically with the name of the image that will show on og:image

that all work with me but image that will show on og:image shows the type of the image in the title for example love.jpg

its show like that

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Love.jpg" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourdomain.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourdomain.com/images/Love.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Liked it? Click Here for More."/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="yourdomain.com - Love Test?"/>
```

the question is how i hide type jpg in the image title

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Love.jpg" />
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following using [`pathinfo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php):

```
<?php
function random_pic($dir, $nf=3) {
    $files = glob($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.jpg');
    shuffle($files);
    return array_pop($files);
}

$path = 'images';
$file_images = random_pic($path, 1);
$fileinfo = pathinfo($file_images);
$image  = file_get_contents($file_images);
$og_img = base64_encode($image); 
?>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $fileinfo['filename'] ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://YourDomain.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://YourDomain.com/<?= $file_images ?>" />
```

Comment: if PHP version >=PHP 5.2.0

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe - I hope he is using a later version. PHP 5.2 is very old and shouldn't used anymore.

Comment: Yes but we never know, some beginners just use 5.1 on localhost